# Matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm running a script calling a function and within the function it takes a value from the matrix. Matlab seems to be thinking that the value is still a matrix and is asking for a . when its squared. I should be getting a single value out of my matrix. Any help would be appreciated!

Output

Error using  ^ 
Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.
To compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead.

Error in ls_error (line 11)
    partialSum = (vi - yi)^2;

This is the script i'm running

```
Exp1H1 = 35.6;
Exp1H2 = 24.7;
Exp2H1 = 46.8;
Exp2H2 = 37.8;
Exp3H1 = 45.7;
Exp3H2 = 36.4;
Exp4H1 = 47.7;
Exp4H2 = 39.2;

Radius = 3.75;
L = 10;

ArrayOfHeightDiff = [(Exp1H1-Exp1H2),(Exp2H1-Exp2H2),(Exp3H1-Exp3H2),       (Exp4H1-Exp4H2)];
dhdl = ArrayOfHeightDiff./L
ArrayOfDarcys = [0.29,0.25,0.26,0.23];
v_meas = ((ArrayOfDarcys.*1000)./60)./(pi*Radius^2)

K = [-0.3 : 0.1 : 0.5];

for ii = 1 : 1 : length(K)
    ExportSum = ls_error(dhdl, v_meas, K)
    ExportSum(1,ii) = ExportSum
end
```

This is the function

```
function [ExportSum] = ls_error(dhdl, v_meas, K)

total = 0;           
L = length(dhdl);   

for ii = 1 : 1 : L
    dhdl1 = dhdl(1,ii);
    vi = v_meas(1,ii);        

    yi = 1*K* dhdl1;    
    partialSum = (vi - yi)^2;   
    total = total + partialSum;     
end

ExportSum = total;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In the following code, you create a 1xN vector `K`, and pass it into ls_error:

```
K = [-0.3 : 0.1 : 0.5];

for ii = 1 : 1 : length(K)
    ExportSum = ls_error(dhdl, v_meas, K)
    ExportSum(1,ii) = ExportSum
end
```

You then use this vector `K`and multiply it by two scalars, which will produce a 1xN vector:

```
yi = 1*K* dhdl1;    
partialSum = (vi - yi)^2;
```

The `partialSum` calculation is then giving you the error, as you can't perform a scalar square on a vector.

From your code, what I think you meant to do was this:

```
for ii = 1 : 1 : length(K)
    ExportSum = ls_error(dhdl, v_meas, K(ii))
    ExportSum(1,ii) = ExportSum
end
```

Where instead of passing in the entire vector `K`, you just want to pass in the `ii`th element to use within the calculation of `ExportSum` which you return.

As a further note, once this bug is solved, it may be worth looking at *vectorising* your Matlab function (i.e. deliberately passing it the entire vector of `K` and computing all of the `ExportSum`s at once using vector arithmetic instead of inside a loop), which will hugely speed up your code. It can be complicated, but will likely give you a huge decrease in execution time.

Answer (score 1):

In the calling script you define `K` as a vector. Therefore, in the function `yi` is a vector too. Hence the error in `(vi - yi)^2`.